# Control can't be edited; it's bound to an unknown field [FieldName]

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 bugs beginning to show up in my app, both in subforms. New text boxes, labels and check boxes will only display in design view.

Bigger problem: I can add a check box by dragging it from the field list but get the error 'Control can't be edited; it's bound to an unknown field [FieldName]' when I attempt to click it in form view. 
I can edit the value directly in the table and I can edit the value in the form's underlying query as well.

I've tried decompiling/recompiling and importing all my objects into a new database. I tried using a different machine to see if there was something wrong on mine. nada

This is an existing application with hundreds of man hours into it. I can't just start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  After many hours of work I discovered that all of a sudden I had to add the table name to the Control Source property.

Go to the properties for the control and add the table name i.e. tbl_MyTable.MyField.

I have no idea why Access sees an ambiguity problem all of a sudden for just that one field but that was obviously the case.

Comment: I experienced this problem while trying to add a field into a subform while I was editing the Parent form. Using the table name did not help, but did resolve problem by closing the parent form and editing the sub-form directly.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem - but it was reversed, I had to remove the table name.. man Access sucks so much

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this - It took me a while to realize because the error statement only persisted while data list item was click-depressed. It turns out in my case that somehow a number of spaces existed in the Control Source property. I found this when I entered the table name in the field and the error statement switched from ***Control can't be edited; it's bound to an unknown field '(bunch of spaces)          '***  to ***Control can't be edited; it's bound to an unknown field [tableName]***. After deleting  the [tablename] and ensuring no spaces in *Control Source*, the combobox toggled to 'unbound' and there was peace in the valley.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried adding the table name to no avail.  On the load event of the form, I changed the recordset (same table but filtered using what is passed by me.openargs instead of on the docmd.openform command due to needing the id passed for other things to work) in VBA.  I thought that once you set the form to the recordset, you were done and could close the recordset.  Not so, leave the recordset open until you actually leave the form or this error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Change the control source from "=[Some_Value_in_Table]" to [Some_Value_in_Table]. To be more precise remove the equal to sign.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these things - to no avail.  I had a few fields bound and only one of them was causing grief - the others were fine.  I swapped the Control Source around between controls to isolate the issue - it was definitely only related to the field somehow - after refreshing external links, removing and re-adding the offending field from the Access query opening and closing the offending form - everything somehow fell into place - I can't say exactly what fixed the problem - but my life can now return to normal!  In a nutshell - these are the steps I followed:
* refresh links to external table
* remove and re-add fields in query
* confirm the the field is editable at the query level
* copy and paste the table.fieldName from the query's sql statement
* save - close query
* paste into the Control Source
* save and close form!
Good luck!